# MudBlazor Generic Server Side Table Pagination Issues

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am attempting to make a more "generic" MudTable on Blazor Server, as I use them frequently across my application. I made one for "client side" data, which works just fine. I am now trying to make one for server side data.

My code somewhat works, as the data loads perfectly fine and changing the records per page also works perfectly fine. My issue is with changing the page on my paginator. I'm not sure what exactly is going on, but hooking up a debugger to my PageChanged function on my Paging.razor component shows that the function gets called twice, back to back. One to change the page to the one I clicked on, and another which sets selectedPage back to 1. I cannot figure out why it's getting called twice, and why it keeps getting reset back to one every single time.

Some notes:

- Debugging in the `ServerReload` function shows that the data is fetched properly when a page is changed.
- If I force change the value using the debugger in PageChanged(int i) to anything but 1, another call is made to change that value back to 1.
- I am running .NET 7, using the bone-stock Blazor Server template. The only changes made to the configuration was adding MudBlazor, my DbContext and GenericDataService.

Here's my code:

GenericServerTable.razor

```cs
@typeparam TItem


    <MudTable
        Loading="@showSpinner"
        ServerData="@(new Func<TableState, Task<TableData<RowData>>>(ServerReload))"
        T="RowData"
        @ref="table"
        Striped>
    
        <ToolBarContent>
            <MudStack Class="flex-grow-1" Row="true" Spacing="0" Justify="Justify.SpaceBetween">
                <MudStack Row="true">
                    @ToolBarTemplate
                </MudStack>
                <MudSpacer></MudSpacer>
                <Paging @bind-currentPage="@currentPage" @bind-rpp="@rpp" @bind-selectedPage="@selectedPage" totalItems="@tableData.TotalItems" totalPages="@totalPages" />
            </MudStack>
        </ToolBarContent>
        <HeaderContent>

            @HeaderTemplate
        </HeaderContent>
        <RowTemplate Context="item">
            @RowDataTemplate(item.Data)
        </RowTemplate>
        <NoRecordsContent>
            <NoRecordsFound />
        </NoRecordsContent>
        <PagerContent>
            <MudStack Class="flex-grow-1" Row="true" Spacing="0" Justify="Justify.SpaceBetween">
                <MudStack Row="true" Spacing="0"></MudStack>
                <MudSpacer></MudSpacer>
                <Paging Top="false" @bind-currentPage="@currentPage" @bind-rpp="@rpp" @bind-selectedPage="@selectedPage" totalItems="@tableData.TotalItems" totalPages="@totalPages" />
            </MudStack>
        </PagerContent>
    </MudTable>
    
@code {
    
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<TItem> RowDataTemplate { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment HeaderTemplate { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ToolBarTemplate { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Func<int, int, string, string, string, Task<PaginatedResult<TItem>>> ServerReloadFunc { get; set; }
    
    public class RowData : TableRow<TItem> { }

    private MudTable<RowData> table = new();
    private TableData<RowData> tableData = new();

    private int currentPage { get; set; } = 0;
    private int totalPages { get; set; } = 0;
    //private int selectedPage { get; set; } = 1;
    private int _rpp = 50;
    private bool showSpinner = false;
    private int _selectedPage = 1;
    private int selectedPage {
        get => this._selectedPage;
        set {
            if (value != this._selectedPage) {
                this._selectedPage = value;
                ReloadServerData();
            }
        }
    }
    private int rpp {
        get => this._rpp;
        set {
            this._rpp = value;
            // currentPage = 0;
            // selectedPage = 1;
            ReloadServerData();
        }
    }

    private void SelectedPageChange(int page) {
        if (page != selectedPage)
        {
            selectedPage = page;
            currentPage = page - 1;
            ReloadServerData();
            StateHasChanged(); 
        }
    }
    

    protected override void OnInitialized() {
        Console.WriteLine("init");
        ReloadServerData();
    }
    
    private void ReloadServerData() {
        table.ReloadServerData();
    }
    
    private async Task<TableData<RowData>> ServerReload(TableState state) {
        showSpinner = true;
        
        string sortBy = state.SortLabel ?? "name";
        string sortDir = state.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending ? "asc" : "desc";
        
        var items = await ServerReloadFunc.Invoke(rpp, selectedPage, sortBy, sortDir, String.Empty);
        
        var enumerable = items.Data.ToList();
        int totalItems = 0;
        if (!enumerable.Any()) {
            return new TableData<RowData> { Items = new List<RowData>(), TotalItems = 0 };
        }
        totalItems = items.TotalItems;
        totalPages = items.TotalPages;

        tableData.Items = enumerable.Select(x => new RowData { Data = x }).ToList();
        tableData.TotalItems = totalItems;

        showSpinner = false;
        return tableData;
    }
    
}
```

Paging.razor

```cs
@if ((!Top && totalItems >= 10) || Top)
{
    <MudStack Row="true" Spacing="0" AlignItems="AlignItems.Center">
        <MudSelect Class="mr-4 noBreakLabel" Style="width: 100px;" Margin="Margin.Dense" Dense T="int" @bind-Value="recordsPer" Variant="Variant.Outlined" AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter">
            @*<MudSelectItem T="int" Value="2">2</MudSelectItem>*@
            <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="50">50</MudSelectItem>
            <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="100">100</MudSelectItem>
            <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="250">250</MudSelectItem>
            <MudSelectItem T="int" Value="500">500</MudSelectItem>
        </MudSelect>
        <MudText Class="pr-4">
            @(
                $"of {totalItems}"
                )
        </MudText>
        <MudPagination BoundaryCount="2" MiddleCount="3" ShowFirstButton="true" ShowLastButton="true" Rectangular="true" Selected="@selectedPage" Count="@totalPages" Variant="Variant.Outlined" SelectedChanged="PageChanged" />
    </MudStack>
}
@code {
    [Parameter] public bool Top { get; set; } = true;
    [Parameter] public int currentPage { get; set; } = 0;
    [Parameter] public int totalItems { get; set; } = 0;
    [Parameter] public int totalPages { get; set; } = 0;
    [Parameter] public int selectedPage { get; set; } = 1;
    [Parameter] public int rpp { get; set; } = 50;
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<int> rppChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<int> currentPageChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<int> selectedPageChanged { get; set; }

    private int recordsPer
    {
        get => rpp;
        set
        {
            rpp = value;
            totalPages = Decimal.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((decimal)totalItems / (decimal)value));
            rppChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
        }
    }
    private void PageChanged(int i)
    {
        if (i != selectedPage) {
            currentPage = i - 1;
            selectedPage = i;
            StateHasChanged();
            //currentPageChanged.InvokeAsync(i - 1);
            selectedPageChanged.InvokeAsync(i);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Index.razor

```
<GenericServerTable TItem="GenericData" ServerReloadFunc="Test" >
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <MudTh>Name</MudTh>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <RowDataTemplate>
        <MudTd>@context.Name</MudTd>
    </RowDataTemplate>
</GenericServerTable>



@code {
    [Inject] private GenericDataService client { get; set; }
    
    private async Task<PaginatedResult<GenericData>> Test(int rpp, int selectedPage, string sortBy, string sortDirection, string search) {
        
        var result = await client.GetList(rpp, selectedPage, sortBy, sortDirection, search);

        var paginatedResult = new PaginatedResult<GenericData>() {
            Data = result,
            TotalItems = result.FirstOrDefault().TotalItems,
            TotalPages = result.FirstOrDefault().TotalPages
        };
        
        return paginatedResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is kinda late, but could this be due to the fact that you have two paging instances in your table, so both of them call the event?

Comment: Also what does your TableRow class from which RowData inherrits look like?

Comment: I recreated your site to the best of my abilities (Some info on TableRow would be helpfull and some css data), and for me it actually seems to work.

Comment: Small correction it gets called tweice for me as well, but I do not get a reset.

Comment: @SMSTJ thanks for your response! Considering that you are not getting a reset then it has to be with my fetch code. With all the info I've gathered so far, something in my backend / db must be overwriting it.

Comment: Thats interesting. Id still really like to know what your TableRow and maybe PaginatedResult classes look like. And if possible your GetList Method in your client service.